# creating a Chat room in Flex

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, apache-flex, blazeds

I want to implement a Chat room in Flex 3.
Please help me.

Thanks!!

Comment: I'm not sure that's really a constructive question. Get to it and if you run into issues, then ask...

Answer (score 2):

Download [BlazeDS](http://opensource.adobe.com/wiki/display/blazeds/download+blazeds+3) and you will find a chat example included in the samples .